# Regex to match date with string as month

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string:

```
var cur = "t+20d";
```

And I want to match it. That part I already did with

```
if(cur.match(/^[t]\+[0-9]{2,4}[dmyw]/i))
```

Now I also need to be able to match this string, and prefably in the same regex

```
var cur = "10may15+20d";
```

I have tried

```
  cur.match(/^([t]|([0-9]{1,2}(jan|feb|march|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sept|okt|nov|dec)))\+[0-9]{2,4}[dmyw]/i)
```

But it doens't work as intended.

if I try to compile the subpart I get two pieces of array instead of one

```
 cur.match(/[0-9]{1,2}(jan|feb|march|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sept|okt|nov|dec)/i);
 //yields ["10MaY", "MaY"]
```

And this worries me about false positives.

I'm really really rusty at regex, last time I tried to make a complicated regex was 15 years ago and that was in perl, so I could really use some help with this one. I know ors and grouped matches are possible, I just can't figure out how to do it anymore so some help is appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to match the number which exists after the month.

```
^(t|[0-9]{1,2}(?:jan|feb|march|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sept|okt|nov|dec)\d+)\+[0-9]{2,4}[dmyw]
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/pD8hO1/1)

Comment: You pointed me in the correct direction. Thanks for that. Mabe you could edit the question to state that it is the group operator `:?` is the thing I was looking for to make it a more complete answer for those who come here via google.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of [@AvinashRaj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3297613/avinash-raj) who pointed me to the group  operator ?: with his regex I managed to compose this regexfor my uses and i'm posting it here for future users who might need to match a date string like this. ddmmmyy

```
cur  = "10-apr-1115+20d";
cur.match(/^(?:t|[0-9]{1,2}(?:jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|okt|nov|dec|[-\/](?:[0-9]{1,2}|jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|okt|nov|dec)[-\/])(?:[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{4}))\+[0-9]{1,4}[dmyw]/igm);
```